# How to perform loading text with brackets using numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

The following code generates a matrix `X` (I use Python 2.7):

```
X = [random.randint(0, 2 ** 8) for _ in range(num)]

# Removes duplicates
X = list(set(X))

# Transforms into string representation
X = [('{0:0' + str(8) + 'b}').format(x) for x in X]

# Transforms each bit into an integer.
X = np.asarray([list(map(int, list(x))) for x in X], dtype=np.int8)
```

Which is deliberately in this form (Assuming I generate only 10 numbers):

```
[[1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1]]
```

My goal is to store and load it again (with square brackets) using `numpy`. In the storing process, I use `numpy.savetxt('dataset.txt', X, fmt='%d')` (which removes the square brackets :( ). The problem is that I want to load it back into in the same shape shown above (including the square brackets). Using `numpy.loadtxt(StringIO('dataset.txt'))` does it help. I am not sure how to implement that. I tried to find an (efficient) trick to do so but really I am stuck!! Any help is REALLY appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You can do the `savetxt/loadtxt` round trip with a simple array like this. Just don't expect to see [] in the file.  But if you don't need a human-readable file, the `save/load` pair is better (and faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use np.save() which will save it as a binary file and use np.load() to get it back.